# Constructing and optimizing a polynomial with constraints

Tags: polynomials, optimization

The problem is to construct a polynomial $f(x)$ (say, of order $7$) and to minimize $x$ according to the constraints given below.
$$
\text{minimize $x$ such that} \\
f(0) = a \\
f'(0) = b \\
f(x) = c \\
f'(x) = d  
$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is my first question so any suggestions to rephrase the question will also be appreciated.

Comment: Note the proper use of \text{} in MathJax, per my edit.

Comment: You might want to start with $f(x) = A x^2 + B x + C$. Calculate $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ for this polynomial and derive the coefficients from the four equations.

Comment: So $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are given, along with the degree of the polynomial (say, 7), and you are to solve for $x$ and coefficients (eight of them for a degree 7 polynomial)? Without additional constraints, the problem is unbounded. Pick any arbitrary (large, negative) value of $x$, and you can find coefficients satisfying all four constraints.

Comment: I forgot to mention that x is non negative.  if the degree of the polynomial is 3 ?